is there a way to do something like a KVM but between OS on the same computer?
I need Windows to play games and modify them. Simply using Linux compatibility isn't enough.
However I'm starting to hate Windows because I cannot know or control all the information it sends, and who it sends it to, and with Windows 12 coming with its "AI" integration this will only get worse.
Is there a way to install Windows on a SSD, a Linux disto on an other SSD, and then switch relatively quickly between each of them?
The windows OS would be limited to playing/modding games.
On the linux distro I would code, do 3d modeling, heavy GPU computation and such.
I think the data drive used by linux should also be made inaccessible to Windows, I don't want Windows too look at what is inside.
I don't want to have to reboot to switch from one OS to the other, I want to switch from the two OS as if I had 2 computers with a KVM, is that even possible?

No. But maybe check out Looking Glass, which solves this problem using VMs and GPU passthrough.

Please use normal capitalization. It helps us readers better understand you. A virtual machine should probably work fine, though depending on the game virtualization may cause some issues. There isn't a method of running two OSes "natively" or "directly" on system hardware simultaneously. It simply isn't a thing these days.

You can:

Virtualize, which supports quickly switching, and allows controlling access between the different systems, though this may cause issues running certain games that may have more advanced hardware requirements.

Dual-boot, which doesn't allow the "quick switching" you're asking for, but will allow better game compatibility and function.


There is no current system that allows to OSes to run simultaneously directly on the same hardware, which is what would be required in order to support the quick switching ability you are requesting.

wouldn't there be a way to put the os in hibernation, then restore the other os that was also in hibernation?

No, and there are plenty of questions here regarding that specific topic. Sleeping or  OSes put a lock on the drive so it cannot be used by another OS, hibernating Windows uses a restore file. Booting from GRUB into a hibernated Windows will not load from that hyberfil.sys file and you'll lose data.  You cannot sleep one OS and switch to another in a dual boot config.
